# How to send data from HTML to .MDF file, retrieve data from .MDF to .EXE, and return result from .EXE to HTML?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, windows

How can I send a group of data from HTML to .MDF file which located in the same folder?

There is an .EXE (written in C#) file to process the data. After data processing done, how to notify and instruct the HTML to retrieve the data and display to user?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using any type of server to process user request?

Comment: Currently using Microsoft SQL.